# Print and return in one function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have function like this one:

```
def get_list_of_movies(table):

    #some code here

    print(a_list)
    return a_list
```

Reason why I want to use print and return is that I'm using this function in many places. So after calling this function from menu I want to get printed list of content.

This same function I'm using in another function - just to get list. Problem is - when I call this function it prints list as well.

Question: How to prevent function from executing print line when its used in another function just to get list?

This is part of exercise so I can't define more functions / split this or soo - I'm kind of limited to this one function.

*Edit: Thank you for all answers! I'm just beginner but you showed me ways in python(programming in general) that I never thought of! Using second parameter (boolin) is very cleaver. I do learn here a lot!*

Comment: You could add another input argument, a boolean say `printOutput` which defaults to `False`.

Comment: print(get_list_of_movies) where the functions is called? or use flag variables as arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a separate argument with a default value of `None` to control the printing. Pass

```
def get_list_of_movies(table, printIt=False):
    ...
    if printIt:
        print(a_list)
    return a_list

...

movies = get_list_of_movies(table, printIt=True)
```

Another approach is to pass `print` itself as the argument, where the default value is a no-op:

```
def get_list_of_movies(table, printer=lambda *args: None):
    ...
    printer(a_list)
    return a_list

...

movies = get_list_of_movies(table, printer=print)
```

This opens the door to being able to customize exactly how the result is print; you are effectively adding an arbitrary callback to be performed on the return value, which admittedly can be handled with a custom pass-through function as well:

```
def print_it_first(x):
    print(x)
    return x

movies = print_it_first(get_list_of_movies(table))
```

This doesn't require any special treatment of `get_list_of_movies` itself, so is probably preferable from a design standpoint.

Comment: I really like that second idea! It seems incredibly versatile.

Comment: It's an example of [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: I think I've got a working no-op now. I'll leave it to the reader to adjust the argument list as necessary :)

Answer (score 1):

A completely different approach is to *always* print the list, but control where it gets printed *to*:

```
def get_list_of_movies(table, print_to=os.devnull):
    ...
    print(a_list, file=location)
    return a_list

 movies = get_list_of_movies(table, print_to=sys.stdout)
```

The `print_to` argument can be any file-like object, with the default ensuring no output is written anywhere.